# Wordpress Custom Taxonomy when importing posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently importing posts from an external source and importing them in the Products Custom Post Type.
I am trying to import them with a Custom Taxonomy.

```
     'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($result->Product_Name) ,

     'meta_input' => array(
         'Coupon_start_date' => $result->Coupon_start_date,
         'Coupon_end_date' => $result->Coupon_end_date,
         'New_Price' => $result->New_Price,
         'Old_Price' => $result->Old_Price,
         'tax_input' => array($category->'Store_Type' => array($category->'StoreA' )),
     ) ,
     'post_type' => 'product',

     'post_status' => 'publish',

 );
 wp_insert_post($cupon);
$pid = wp_insert_post($cupon);
```

The taxonomy slug is 'Store_Type', where I have StoreA and StoreB. I tried all the available options, but i just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
    'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($result->Product_Name) ,
    
    'meta_input' => array(
        'Coupon_start_date' => $result->Coupon_start_date,
        'Coupon_end_date' => $result->Coupon_end_date,
        'New_Price' => $result->New_Price,
        'Old_Price' => $result->Old_Price,
        'tax_input' => array($category->'Store_Type' => array($category->'StoreA' )),
    ) ,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    
    'post_status' => 'publish',
```

Is this the arguments array that you are passing for creating a new post ? If yes, then there is a mistake in the array. You have added 'tax_input' key inside the 'meta_input' array. You can try using below arguments array.

```
'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($result->Product_Name) ,

'meta_input' => array(
    'Coupon_start_date' => $result->Coupon_start_date,
    'Coupon_end_date' => $result->Coupon_end_date,
    'New_Price' => $result->New_Price,
    'Old_Price' => $result->Old_Price,
) ,

'tax_input' => array($category->'Store_Type' => array($category->'StoreA' )),

'post_type' => 'product',

'post_status' => 'publish',
```

Hope that works for you.